# Side of a square attached to two triangles

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Solve for $l$

[image: Figure 1]
I tried to solve this for $l$ with trigonometry, but I stopped at $l^2+4-2l\cdot \cos(x)=16, l^2 + 4 +2l\cdot \sin(x)=25$, where $x$ is the angle of the left triangle between 4 and $l$.
So I've tried with Heron's, and got stuck with some square roots...

According to WolframAlpha, the answer must be something around 3.71374

Any ideas?

------SOLVED----------

Okay, so, thanks to Narasimham I've seen that I took cosine formula wrong, and thanks to cosmo5 I've been able to solve it, here's the solution:

Start with cosine formula
\begin{matrix}
5^2 & = & l^2+4-2\cdot2\cdot l\cdot \cos(270^\circ - \alpha))\\ 
4^2 & = & l^2+4-2\cdot2\cdot l \cdot \cos(\alpha)
\end{matrix}

Rearrange teh two equation
\begin{matrix}
441-42l^2+l^4 & = &16l^2\cdot\sin^2(\alpha))\\ 
144-24l^2+l^4 & = &16l^2 \cdot \cos^2(\alpha)
\end{matrix}

find this quadratic formula
\begin{matrix}
585-66l^2+2l^4=16l^2
\end{matrix}

and then found this solutions
\begin{matrix}
+\sqrt{\dfrac{41+\sqrt{511}}{2}}\\ 
+\sqrt{\dfrac{41-\sqrt{511}}{2}}\\
-\sqrt{\dfrac{41+\sqrt{511}}{2}}\\
-\sqrt{\dfrac{41-\sqrt{511}}{2}}
\end{matrix}

Then, discart the negative ones
\begin{matrix}
\sqrt{\dfrac{41+\sqrt{511}}{2}}\\ 
\sqrt{\dfrac{41-\sqrt{511}}{2}}
\end{matrix}

Comment: @ GABRIEL DELGADO: You missed out a factor 2 in your cosine formula at the start ... resulting in erroneous calculations. When correctly done we get $ L^4-41 L^2+292.5=0$ whose roots appear in my answer. I commented only for correctness sake, never mind the voting accepting etc.

Comment: This problem was featured on the Mind Your Decisions youtube channel: https://youtu.be/iszucjbTh5I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `Mathematica`; Using Cosine formula of a triangle, three unknowns and three variables. Numerical solution.

```
  eq={20.-16 Cos[al]==L^2, 29-20 Cos[bt]==L^2,41.-40 Cos[al+bt]== 2 L^2};   NSolve[eq,{al,bt,L}]
```

[image: al,bt description]

al->0.829607,bt->0.140595,L->3.03271},{al->2.4004,bt->1.71139,L->5.63938}}`

I have checked by approximate `Geogebra` construction. Two cases arise when the node is  inside and the other when it is outside the square. Rough sketch attached including all trigonometric parameters.

To me it is convincing enough.

[image: Geom SQUARE constuction]

Answer (score 3):

Rearrange the two equations as
$$l^2-12=2l\cos x \quad , \quad l^2-21=-2l\sin x$$

On squaring both and adding, $x$ is eliminated,
$$(l^2-12)^2+(l^2-21)^2=(2l)^2$$
$$\Rightarrow 2(l^2)^2-70l^2+585=0$$

and a quadratic in $l^2$ is obtained. Its value can be computed using the quadratic formula.

To compute $l$, remember to take the square root of $l^2$. WA confirms $l=3.71374$.